# Difference between MongoDB's find and findone calls

Tags: mongodb

I am working on a project and I am unsure if there is a difference between the way the `find` cursor works and the way the `findOne` cursor works. Is findOne just a wrapper for `find().limit(1)`? I was looking around for it and maybe someone knows if mongodb has a special method for it or not. I am working with the PHP API for mongodb if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Based on my own benchmarks, `find().limit(1)` is orders of magnitude *faster* than `findOne()`.**

There is either an error in the MongoDB documentation or a bug in `findOne()`. `findOne()` performs more like `find().limit(N)` where N is the number of documents the query would return. I figured this out while trying to figure out why my simple queries were so slow!

**update:** response from a 10gen (MongoDB) engineer:

> The two queries you are executing are very different. A find query
>   returns a cursor, this is essentially a no-operation scenario, as no
>   actual data is returned (only the cursor information). If you call
>   findOne, then you are actually returning the data and closing the
>   cursor. The docs should definitely be clearer :-)

**Update:** Indeed, if the `find().limit(1)` document is retrieved, the orders of magnitude speed difference seems to disappear. Also, I could not reproduce the major speed difference with the MongoDB JavaScript driver. I originally benchmarked using the MongoDB Java driver.

Comment: Great find. Important question, though: Do your benchmarks account for the extra operations you'd have to do with `find().limit(1)` in the course of normal programming (like actually retrieving the data and closing the cursor) that `findOne()` automatically does for you anyway?

Comment: @Nick: I think extra operations were covered. I was finding a random document (http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/random-attribute/), getting the document with .next() and removing it from the collection. I didn't manually close any cursors...

Comment: @Leftium then i must ask is it faster to do a find.limit(1) and then get the cursur value or is it faster to do a findone()

Comment: @WojonsTech: a quick benchmark in JS shows findOne() is actually faster. Results may vary by driver/platform, though. For example, I could not reproduce the orders of magnitude speed difference in JS that I originally observed with the Java driver.

Comment: Leftium, I would edit your answer to stress that when you actually retrieve the document (which you normally would), the two functions are actually identical, just as the documentation states. Right now someone will likely read the bolded line at the beginning of your answer and conclude that if they want to retrieve one document, `findOne()` is worse than `find().limit(1)`, which is incorrect.

Comment: Is the information in this answer still relevant?

Comment: Also curious if this is still a performance tip still applicable today in 2017. Also - does this apply to Mongoose models? (ie: `Model.find(q).limit(1)` VS `Model.findOne(q)`)

Comment: @bigp This is not a valid performance tip, the two methods are identical when actually retrieving the document.

Answer (score 10):

`findOne()` is indeed [syntactic sugar](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tutorial#Tutorial-%7B%7BfindOne%28%29%7D%7D%5CSyntacticSugar) for `find().limit(1)`, **given that you are actually retrieving the document** (as opposed to just returning the cursor with `find()`).

See [Leftium's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7573/difference-between-mongodbs-find-and-findone-calls/7587#7587) and updates for more detail.

Comment: okay thank you i dont like using synimus functions in my programming would rather put limit one myself just so all my code is easy to track down.

Comment: Actually in benchmarks findOne() a bit faster than find().limit(1).

Comment: @DairT'arg - If you have sources or data to back up this claim, by all means post an answer with the details! From what I've gathered so far, they *should* be identical as long as you are retrieving the document in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

The source code may helps a lot.

It's java but I guess it can help, too.

The `findOne()`,

```
DBObject findOne(DBObject o, DBObject fields, DBObject orderBy, ReadPreference readPref,
                 long maxTime, TimeUnit maxTimeUnit) {

    QueryOpBuilder queryOpBuilder = new QueryOpBuilder().addQuery(o).addOrderBy(orderBy)
                                                        .addMaxTimeMS(MILLISECONDS.convert(maxTime, maxTimeUnit));

    if (getDB().getMongo().isMongosConnection()) {
        queryOpBuilder.addReadPreference(readPref);
    }

    Iterator<DBObject> i = find(queryOpBuilder.get(), fields, 0, -1, 0, getOptions(), readPref, getDecoder());

    DBObject obj = (i.hasNext() ? i.next() : null);
    if ( obj != null && ( fields != null && fields.keySet().size() > 0 ) ){
        obj.markAsPartialObject();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

And here is `find()`

```
public DBCursor find( DBObject ref ){
    return new DBCursor( this, ref, null, getReadPreference());
}
```

As we can see that `findOne()` calls `find()` in it self, gets all the `DBOject` in `i` and then return the first.

Answer (score -1):

You must check this link ...

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/finding-documents.html

1. find    -  option return  array []
2. findOne -  option return document {}